# How do I pass variable in css import in ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dynamic, react-router

I have issues with my **css** cache,
when I do some changes it doesn't reflect, every time I have to do hard refresh or clear my browser cache.

```
var variable = time;
import '../public/assets/css/a.css?time=variable';
require ('../public/assets/css/2?varible');
```

Help me out to load new css and js every time in my application.

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried holding the SHIFT key while you hit the page refresh icon? That usually clears the cache entry for that one site

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Chrome or Chromium, open up the developer tools, and make sure that the `Disable cache` checkbox is turned on in the `Network` tab. This way, the browser will ignore the cache while the developer tools window is open.

Alternatively, you could append a hash string to the name of the generated bundle. Assuming you're using webpack, you could add this to your build config (just an example):

```
output: {
  path: ...,
  filename: '[name]-[hash].js'
}
```

Comment: i'm not using webpack even i didn't see any config file
In my root directory there is package.json file only and public, src, node_modules and build directory - i'm new in Reactjs.

Comment: Well, then my first suggestion should still work for you.

Comment: What about all other browsers? No any other way to handle from my code ?

Comment: I thought you were concerned about your code not updating during development. I'm sure there are similar settings in other browsers. For production, however, this strategy will not suffice, you'll need to include something like hash generation into your build mechanism. With webpack, this is fairly straightforward, as described above. If you're using gulp, then there is [gulp-rev](https://github.com/sindresorhus/gulp-rev), which does something similar. So it depends on your build tools.

Comment: Thank you @assan

By the way do you know any sample application built with reactJs with using .jsx or babel with navigation or route using webpack. 
So, i download and start working on them ?

Comment: Do you mean a boilerplate project? If so there are plenty of examples on github. I haven't researched them much, I just wrote my own. If you have time, I suggest you do the same, it's a good learning experience, and it's better to understand what's happening under the hood.